# MySQL SELECT LIKE space encoding issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have spent several hours to solve this problem, but I can't solve it.

One of column contain value like bellow, and the value contain some blank spaces.

```
光学传感器 - 光电二极管
```

I want select all the value equal to "光学传感器 - 光电二极管". But the blank space may be ASCII encoding('\x0a'), or utf8 encoding('\xa0'), So when I execute SQL string LIKE this, will return None.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `icbase_icattrvalue` 
WHERE `value` LIKE  '光学传感器 - 光电二极管'
```

I have try SQL like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `icbase_icattrvalue`
WHERE REPLACE( `value` , '\xa0', ' ' ) LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `icbase_icattrvalue` 
WHERE REPLACE(`value`,  CONVERT(char(160) USING utf8), ' ') 
LIKE  REPLACE('光学传感器 - 电二极管',  CONVERT(char(160) USING utf8), ' ')
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

or some similar SQL string, But they can't help, they all return None.

What should I to , to select value equal to a string, but ignore such space encoding issue.

I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: `LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', '' )`, I guess you wanted to use a space: `LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' )` (note the last `' '` instead of `''`).

Comment: I'm sorry for my careless , Actually I use   SQL string     `LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' ) ` later.

Comment: But also return None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the right answer, I should replace `c2a0`, not `a0`.

NON BREAK SPACE in utf-8 is `c2a0`

And in python unicode is `a0`

I get confused with it, Thanks everybody.

```
SELECT * FROM `icbase_icattrvalue` 
WHERE id = 197193 and 
REPLACE( `value` , UNHEX('c2a0'), ' ' ) = REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', UNHEX('c2a0'),  ' ' );
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Alexander Gelbukh` says in comment i also think that this is due to the incorrect spacing in ur code..

```
SELECT *
FROM `icbase_icattrvalue`
WHERE REPLACE( `value` , '\xa0', ' ' ) LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' )
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my careless , Actually I use   SQL string     `LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' ) ` later.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English, I think I haven't made my question clear.  I should say `Actually I use SQL string  LIKE REPLACE( '光学传感器 - 光电二极管', '\xa0', ' ' )  later` but also return none.  Thanks you help.

Comment: And I answered my question. It's just solve my problem.